# How do I create a function that filters by column and column value?

Tags: python, dataframe, filter

The dataframe looks like this:

```
index      company   body-style  wheel-base  length engine-type  \
 0  alfa-romero  convertible        88.6   168.8        dohc   
 1  alfa-romero  convertible        88.6   168.8        dohc   
 2        audi        sedan        99.4   176.6         ohc
```

I have been trying to use something along this line but is hitting error.

```
def dosomething1(column,value):
    value_name=str(value)
    column_name=str(column)
    newdf=df[df[column_name]==value_name]

dosomething1(company, audi)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You function doesn't have a `return` statement:

It should be:

```
def dosomething1(column,value):
    value_name=str(value)
    column_name=str(column)
    newdf=df[df[column_name]==value_name]
    return newdf
```

When you call your function, the strings should be in quotes, such as:

```
dosomething1('company', 'audi')
```

Comment: how do I create a prompt that allows the user to key in column and value and then loop through the above function to retrieve the output?  I have tried to insert column=input("Enter column name, eg company")
    value=input("Enter column value, eg dodge") before the function but it does not appear to take the input keyed into it